# Why is my second column not printing in the same row

Tags: tables

My second column 'B' is printed in the row below for both of my tables. Here is my code for the same -

```
\begin{table}[!htb]
    \caption{Global caption}
    \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
      \caption{}
      \centering
        \begin{tabular}{ll} % centered columns (4 columns)
        \hline\hline %inserts double horizontal lines
        Column & A & B \\ [0.5ex] % inserts table
        %heading
            \hline % inserts single horizontal line
                Case_A & 10 & 238\\ % inserting body of the table
                Case_B & 10 & 238 \\
                Case_C & 10 & 238 \\
                [1ex] % [1ex] adds vertical space
            \hline %inserts single line
        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
      \centering
        \caption{}
        \begin{tabular}{ll} % centered columns (4 columns)
        \hline\hline %inserts double horizontal lines
            Column & A & B \\ [0.5ex] % inserts table
            %heading
            \hline % inserts single horizontal line
                Case_A & 10 & 238\\
                Case_B & 10 & 238 \\
                Case_C & 10 & 238 \\
                [1ex] % [1ex] adds vertical space
            \hline %inserts single line
        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage} 
\end{table}
```

I have attached a picture to show what I'm exactly looking for -

[image]

Comment: `{lll}` instead of `{ll}`?

Comment: One moral: fix compilation errors before worrying about how the output looks.

Comment: Agreed. This is good advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your table code hasmany errors:

- number of declared columns had to be the same as the number of used, so as mentioned @symbol, `{lll}` instead of `{ll}`
- it is not clear, what should be `Case_A`? Is this in math mode and should be $\mathrm{Case}_A$, or is in text mode as `Case\A` (as used in MWE below) or simple `Case A`
- I would rather use rules defined in the `booktabs` package as double `\hline`
- I suspect, that your tables ar in `table` float actually are sub tables:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
    \caption{Global caption}
    \label{tab:global}
\begin{subtable}[t]{.5\linewidth}
    \caption{}
    \label{subtab:1}
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{lll} % centered columns (3! columns)
    \toprule %instead of inserts double horizontal lines
Column & A   & B    \\
    \midrule
Case\_A & 10 & 238  \\ % inserting body of the table
Case\_B & 10 & 238  \\
Case\_C & 10 & 238  \\
    \midrule
\end{tabular}
\end{subtable}%
\begin{subtable}[t]{.5\linewidth}
    \caption{}
    \label{subtab:2}
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{lll} % centered columns (3! columns)
    \toprule %instead of inserts double horizontal lines
Column & A   & B    \\ 
    %heading
    \midrule % inserts single horizontal line
Case\_A & 10 & 238  \\
Case\_B & 10 & 238  \\
Case\_C & 10 & 238  \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{subtable}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```